# Chrome extension with integrated indexdb database

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to provide Chrome extension with readonly indexdb file integrated into extension files. indexdb file will contains some references that will help user to input data (about 500kb).

How can I do this?

variant 1: provide json file and create database on first run, but there are questions about updating database.

variant 2: generate indexdb file using JS code and extract from Applicatoin\User Data file and put it into extension, but how about compatibility between Chrome version

update:

variant 1 disadvantages, I need to code the update database mechanism, may be in next versions I add some records to json file and I need to compare version in json file and version in indexdb file and if they are different run some update script. In case I provide ready for use indexdb file the database will be updated automatically

variant 2 disadvantages, I created indexdb file and put it into extension (now Chrome 34 is stable) and will distribute my extension among users, in new Chrome version the internal structure of indexdb file will be changed and code can't open pre-created database

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Either way is fine. Add more specific info about what you think are the desadvantages. Chrome supports indexedDb so not sure what you are pondering about

Comment: I have added a bit more info